# Recursion gone Wrong?? Please check

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm supposed to get the size of longest incremental numbers of all given numbers. I find the size in arithmetic way.. But the question is to find it in recursive fashion.. I did it but only the last value is showing up.. I don't know what's wrong.

```
    function findmax(num, u, max) {
    let a = parseInt(num);
    let last = parseInt(a % 10);
    let slast = parseInt((a / 10) % 10);
    if (max > 0) {
        console.log(u + "   " + slast + " " + last);
        if (slast <= last) {
            // console.log("Great");
            return findmax(parseInt(a / 10), u + 1, max - 1);
        } else {
            // Here is the problem.. If I do return findMax(parseInt(a / 10), 1, max - 1) only last value of u is shown is shown.. Now v is always undefined, idk why
            v = findmax(parseInt(a / 10), 1, max - 1);
            // console.log("a");
            if (u >= v) return u;
            else return v;
        }
    }
}

let a = [8897727547, 9876543210, 7778124589, 7778121982, 6723198999, 8000008999, 9800236046];
a.forEach(v => {
    console.log(v + " : " + findmax(v, 1, 9));
});
```

Outputs for the above numbers are : 3, 1, 6, 4, 4, 9, 5

Comment: have a look at Array.prototype.reduce(). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: I'm not trying to add all the numbers to find which will be largest though...

Comment: @AshishBhattarai `reduce` isn’t limited to adding numbers…

Comment: @Kai: But this is an attempt to do this recursively.  `reduce` is simply a nicer form of iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution creates `findMax` by converting the number to a string of digits and then passing it to `streak`.  `streak` is a recursive function that takes an array of digits, and then defaults three parameters: the previous digit, the count of the current streak and the length of the longest streak.

When we run out of digits, we return the current maximum.  When our current digit is at least as large as the previous one, we recur, increasing our current streak by one, and updating our maximum if the new current streak is higher.  If not, we recur, starting over with the current digit as previous, a current streak of one and the existing maximum.

```js
const streak = ([d, ...ds], prev = -1, curr = 0, max = 0) => 
  d == undefined 
    ? max 
  : d >= prev
    ? streak  (ds, d, curr + 1, Math.max (max, curr + 1))
  : streak (ds, d, 1, max)

const findMax = (n) => 
  streak (String (n))

let a = [8897727547, 9876543210, 7778124589, 7778121982, 6723198999, 8000008999, 9800236046];

a .forEach (n => console .log (`${n}: ${findMax(n)}`))
```

## Update

There was a comment about not wanting to use arrays for this.  The array was just a convenience.  It allowed us to destructure the first and remaining values of our string into useful variables.  But there is nothing special about it, and our algorithm works the same with only minor tweaks, if we use a string of digits instead:

```js
const streak = (digits, prev = -1, curr = 0, max = 0) => 
  digits .length == 0 
    ? max 
  : digits [0] >= prev
    ? streak  (digits .slice (1), digits [0], curr + 1, Math.max (max, curr + 1))
  : streak (digits .slice (1), digits [0], 1, max)
```

## Update 2

The wonderful answer from @Thankyou offers a challenge to do this without anything more than the basic mathematical operators and function calls.  It's not hard to write a version of this same algorithm that works this way, but since we were working with digits, it was nothing that came to mind when I first read the question.  Here's a variant:

```js
const streak = (n, prev, curr, max) => 
  n < 1
    ? max 
  : n % 10 <= prev
    ? streak  (n / 10 >> 0, n % 10, curr + 1, curr + 1 > max ? curr + 1 : max)
  : streak (n / 10 >> 0, n % 10, 1, max)

const findMax = (n) => 
  streak (n, -1, 0, 1)

let a = [8897727547, 9876543210, 7778124589, 7778121982, 6723198999, 8000008999, 9800236046];

a .forEach (n => console .log (`${n}: ${findMax(n)}`))
```

Here we break a number `n` into it's final digit `n % 10` and the rest of the digits as a single number `n / 10 >> 0`.  If the `>>` is not familiar, it's a
(truncating) [shift operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Right_shift) for integers.  `n >> 0` for positive numbers is equivalent to `Math .floor (n)`.  So if `n` is `12345`, then `n % 10` is `5` and `n / 10 >> 0` is `1234`.

There are two chief differences from the previous version.  First, I've moved the initialization of the parameters from default parameters in the internal `streak` to arguments supplied by the wrapper function `findMax`.  This has little to do with the main changes here, but somehow this time just felt cleaner.  Second, because it's mathematically easier to break `12345` into `1234` and `5` than to break it into `1` and `2345`, we work from the last digit to the first in this version, which means that we change from a `>=` test to a `<=` one, and also that we have to start `max` off at `1`.

The new function should feel similar to the previous two versions, but in this case it does all this based on mathematical rather than String/Array versions.

Thank you, @Thankyou for noting the possibilities here!

Comment: Thank you for the solution.. I was supposed to do this without any arrays but your code inspired me.. Thank u so much for your time..

Comment: Added a string version.

Comment: didn't get around to finishing my long-winded answer on data abstraction last night. by the time i return your array-free version is already posted! brilliant work Scott :D

Comment: Added a more mathematical version.

Comment: _and_ tail-recursive too :D

Comment: Well, I think all three versions above are tail-recursive, but that [doesn't seem to mean much](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-proper_tail_calls_(tail_call_optimisation)) even years after it was originally specified.

Comment: *Sigh of relief*.. Maybe belows answer was not as hard as I thought to be.. I understood this one.. Will look in detail for @Thank you Answer

Comment: @Scott well it does mean that you can easily make it stack-safe using one of the countless solutions we've explored. And +1 for Safari, for respecting your privacy _and_ language specs :D

Comment: @Thankyou: Yes, I suppose we can do so.  I just wish the vendors would make this automatic!

Answer (score 1):

***"I was supposed to do this without any arrays..."***

Programming with restrictions is fun and forces us to think about solving problems in new ways. In this answer, we will only use primitive features of JavaScript -

1. Numbers, `1`, `2`, `-Infinity`, etc
2. Comparison operators, `==`, `<`, `>=`, `||`, etc
3. Basic arithmetic, `+`, `/`, `%`, `>>`, etc
4. Ternary expressions, `cond ? ifTrue : otherwise`
5. Functions, `(arg1, arg2, ...) => result`

`String` and compound data types like `Array` or `Object` will not be used.

---

**implementation**

Let's start with `findMax` -

```js
const findMax = n =>
  streak                   // <- calculate streak of
    ( pairwise(digits(n))  // <-   pairwise digits
    , tuple(1, -Infinity)  // <-   starting with streak of 1, max streak of -Infinity
    )
```

As we wish for functions to exist, we implement them along the way. Let's see `tuple` -

```js
const tuple = (a, b) =>  // <- tuple of (a,b)
  k => k(a, b)           // <- is a continuation of (a,b)

const car = t =>         // <- car of a tuple
  t((a, _) => a)         // <- is the first element, a

const cdr = t =>         // <- cdr of a tuple
  t((_, b) => b)         // <- is the second element, b

car(tuple(7,9))          // -> 7
cdr(tuple(7,9))          // -> 9
```

Now let's write `digits` -

```js
const nil =
  Symbol("nil")                           // <- empty list sentinel

const digits = n =>
  n < 10                                  // <- when n is a single digit
    ? tuple(n, nil)                       // <- tuple of single digit and nil
    : tuple(n % 10, digits(n / 10 >> 0))  // <- tuple of first digit and rest of digits
```

The digits will be compared pair-wise. Given `8897727547` we want to compare pairs of digits and respond to pairs where the digits are increasing -

```
(8,8) (8,9) (9,7) (7,7) (7,2) (2,7) (7,5) (5,4) (4,7)

  =     <     >     =     >     <     >     >     <
```

We can implement this as `pairwise` -

```js
const pairwise = t =>
  zip(t, skip(t, 1))

const skip = (t, n) =>
  t == nil || n == 0
    ? t
    : cdr(t)

const zip = (t0, t1) =>
  t0 == nil || t1 == nil
    ? nil
    : tuple
        ( tuple(car(t0), car(t1))
        , zip(cdr(t0), cdr(t1))
        )
```

Finally we implement `streak`. As we already saw, it takes a pairwise list of digits and an initial result tuple of `1, -Infinity` -

```js
const streak = (t, r) =>
  t == nil
    ? cdr(r)
    : call
        ( n =>
            streak
              ( cdr(t)
              , tuple(n, max(cdr(r), n))
              )
        , caar(t) >= cadr(t)
            ? car(r) + 1
            : 1
        )
```

Which has simple dependencies `caar`, `cadr`, `max`, and `call` -

```js
const caar = t =>
  car(car(t))

const cadr = t =>
  cdr(car(t))

const max = (a, b) =>
  a > b ? a : b

const call = (f, x) =>
  f(x)
```

Now we run `findMax` with your input examples -

```js
findMax(8897727547) // -> 3
findMax(9876543210) // -> 1
findMax(7778124589) // -> 6
findMax(7778121982) // -> 4
findMax(6723198999) // -> 4
findMax(8000008999) // -> 9
findMax(9800236046) // -> 5
```

---

**free data types and functions**

As a result of this implementation, we ended up with some new data types and generic functions which are useful in all sorts of ways -

1. `tuple` a way to group primitive data together, and even construct lists
2. `car`, `cdr`, `caar`, and `cadr` give us a way to access elements within our tuples
3. `digits` constructs a sequence of tuples, representing single digits of an input number
4. `zip`, `skip`, and `pairwise` give us a generic way to manipulate sequences of tuples
5. `max` for getting the maximum of two values, and `call` for calling a function with an argument

---

**demo**

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const nil =
  Symbol("nil")

const tuple = (a, b) =>
  k => k(a, b)

const car = t =>
  t((a, _) => a)

const cdr = t =>
  t((_, b) => b)

const caar = t =>
  car(car(t))

const cadr = t =>
  cdr(car(t))

const digits = n =>
  n < 10
    ? tuple(n, nil)
    : tuple(n % 10, digits(n/10 >> 0)))

const skip = (t, n) =>
  t == nil || n == 0
    ? t
    : cdr(t)

const zip = (t0, t1) =>
  t0 == nil || t1 == nil
    ? nil
    : tuple
        ( tuple(car(t0), car(t1))
        , zip(cdr(t0), cdr(t1))
        )

const pairwise = t =>
  zip(t, skip(t, 1))

const max = (a, b) =>
  a > b ? a : b

const call = (f, x) =>
  f(x)

const streak = (t, r) =>
  t == nil
    ? cdr(r)
    : call
        ( n =>
            streak
              ( cdr(t)
              , tuple(n, max(cdr(r), n))
              )
        , caar(t) >= cadr(t)
            ? car(r) + 1
            : 1
        )

const findMax = n =>
  streak
    ( pairwise(digits(n))
    , tuple(1, -Infinity)
    )

console.log(8897727547, findMax(8897727547)) // 3
console.log(9876543210, findMax(9876543210)) // 1
console.log(7778124589, findMax(7778124589)) // 6
console.log(7778121982, findMax(7778121982)) // 4
console.log(6723198999, findMax(6723198999)) // 4
console.log(8000008999, findMax(8000008999)) // 9
console.log(9800236046, findMax(9800236046)) // 5
```

---

**additional reading**

If you're curious where names like `car`, `cdr`, `caar`, and `cadr` come from, see [Racket: Pairs and Lists](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html).

---

**alternatives**

This of course is not the only way to solve the problem without using arrays. Scott's wonderful and straightforward answer could easily be changed to use lesser features and still arrive at the correct result. As is often the case with programming, there are countless ways to solve any specific problem, each involving techniques that make distinct trade offs. Anyhow, I hope this answer was able to teach you something fun about programming with restrictions.

Comment: I have a huge grin imagining the (presumably beginner) OP's instructor seeing this as a solution to the assignment!  I do love me some LISP!  I'm surprised, seeing the names `car`, `cdr`, etc., that the root is called `tuple` rather than `cons`.  :D

Comment: haha, yeah me too! I first used `cons` (short for *construct*) but opted for `tuple` which at least has _some_ relatability. I should make a note of that though, just so the learner can further connect to its origin.

Comment: Updated my answer to do what you pointed out: do the same thing with only function calls and mathematical operators.  It's much shorter than this answer, but also much less educational.

Comment: Usually, I choose either `cons/car/cdr` or `pair/first/rest`, although `tuple` is a possible substitute for `pair`.  I don't usually use it because `pair` seems more explicit.  I've sometimes used `list`, but that's really not precise either.

Comment: I cannot understand a thing.. But doesn't stop me from appreciating the beauty (or the horror)

Comment: @Ashish there's a lesson here I didn't spell out explicitly. When you create an Array, `a = ["x", "y"]` how does the computer store that? When you access `a[0]` how does the computer retrieve `"x"`, and likewise `a[1]` retrieve `"y"`? We developed and understanding that these _just work_ and we aren't required to know the deep internals to use them. The same is true for `t = tuple("x","y")` and `car(t)` retrieves `"x"` and `cdr(t)` retrieves `"y"` - you don't have to understand them but you can use them intuitively as they _just work_.

Comment: This is called **data abstraction** and the primary advantage is that it's a black box. The user doesn't need to understand complex internals yet can intuitively utilize sophisticated programs. The other primary advantage is that it's a black box! This means the maintainer can change the internals without the user knowing. So long as the module behaves to the specification, the maintainer is free to make updates or optimizations without the user even knowing :D Often you will find yourself on both sides of that line, maintainer _and_ user, and you reap the benefits of both sides.